# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'create_png'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, graphviz, decision-tree, pydot

This classifies the data as a decision tree. The decision tree is created but I am not able to view the decision tree.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets, tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = datasets.load_iris()
f = open('decision_tree_data.txt')
x_train = []
y_train = []
for line in f:
    line = np.asarray(line.split(),dtype = np.float32)
    x_train.append(line[:-1])
    y_train.append(line[:-1])
x_train = np.asmatrix(x_train)
y_train = np.asmatrix(y_train)
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydot
from IPython.display import Image
dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file=dot_data,  
                     feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                     class_names=iris.target_names,  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True)  
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Most notably, we need you to include the *entire* error message as well as enough data to get us to the problem point.

Comment: Overall, it appears that `graph` is a list, not the expected pydot object.  Are you missing a `todot` conversion?  Sorry; I'm no expert on this package.

Comment: maybe you should try install pydotplus, and replace pydot in your code with pydotplus. Pydot seems to be inactive for some years.

Comment: What do you mean "not able to view", is it blank, do you get an error message, do you get jumbled text, etc.?

Comment: @Prune  When i did print the graph i got :  [<pydot.Dot object at 0x1139738d0>]

Comment: That's the first step to debugging.  Now I'm a bit puzzled.  Can you please include those lines (the print and the result) in your original post?  Also include the entire error message (full text and traceback).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `pydot.graph_from_dot_data` [returns](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/35a8d858bd9da0b37268fe9b317fe4895387e75f/pydot.py#L235) a `list` [in `pydot >= 1.2.0`](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/35a8d858bd9da0b37268fe9b317fe4895387e75f/ChangeLog#L32) (in contrast to earlier versions of `pydot`).

The reason was to homogenize the output, which in the past was a `list` if two graphs were returned, but a graph if a single graph was returned. Such branching is a common source of errors in user code (simple is better than complex [[PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)]).

The change applies to all functions that call the function `dot_parser.parse_dot_data`, which now returns [a `list` in all cases](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/35a8d858bd9da0b37268fe9b317fe4895387e75f/dot_parser.py#L545).

To address the error, you need to unpack the single graph that you expect:

```py
graph, = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
```

This statement also asserts that a single graph is returned. So if this assumption doesn't hold, and more graphs are returned, this unpacking will catch it. In contrast, `graph = (...)[0]` won't.

Relevant `pydot` issues:

- https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/149
- https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/159