# How to visualize all the decision tree of the random forest using graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, graphviz

I want to visualize each of the Decision Tree in the Random Forest. For which the code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline    

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


boston=load_boston()
boston_df=pd.DataFrame(boston.data,columns=boston.feature_names)
boston_df['Price']=boston.target
newX=boston_df.drop('Price',axis=1)
newY=boston_df['Price']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(newX, newY, test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
original_regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 0)
original_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)


from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
import pydotplus


dot_data = StringIO()
for tree_in_forest in original_regressor.estimators_:
export_graphviz(tree_in_forest, out_file=dot_data, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True,feature_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN','INDUS','CHAS','NOX','RM','AGE','DIS','RAD','TAX','PTRATIO','B','LSTAT'], node_ids = True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

The error I am getting is:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'create_png'`

Most of the solutions is updating the package from `pydot` to `pydotplus`. In my case, I am already using `pydotplus`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569763/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-create-png?rq=1) the function `pydot.graph_from_dot_data` returns a list if there are multiple graphs. I am assuming the error is because of this. If so, how do we solve this problem?

Comment: Please always tag Python questions [tag:python] (not just [tag:python-3.x]), so they get seen by Python users.

Comment: `'list' object has no attribute 'create_png'` is telling you that `graph` is a list. Please add more details and rerun with current version of packages.

Comment: "how do we solve this problem" The problem hints at the data not being what you think it is. Ultimately, you have to decide how to interpret your data.